# How to pass bsh shared arrayList as a parameter while calling java function in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to call java method having arrayList as parameter from Jmeter.
I have used bsh.shared namespace for arraylist.

**BeanShell Sampler:**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

ArrayList docIDListArray = new ArrayList();
docIDListArray.add("112233"));
bsh.shared.docIDList = docIDListArray;
```

Now I want to pass this bsh.shared.docIDList as parameter in java method call in JSR223 Sampler.

**JSR223 Sampler:**

```
import main.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

jmeter j = new jmeter();
j.writeExcel(bsh.shared.docIDList);
```

It is giving error as below:
Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: bsh for class Script79

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think you have `bsh.shared` namespace in Groovy, it's [Beanshell feature](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables)
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so I would recommend [switching from Beanshell to Groovy completely.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead)

   You can use [`vars.putObject()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) function if you want to pass the arraylist between Samplers or [`props.put()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put(K,%20V)) function if you want to pass the arraylist between threads/thread gruops

Comment: I need to call java method I have created in my project.
Will that be possible from beanshell?

Comment: If you drop the .class file or .jar to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)  (don't forget the dependencies if any) it will be possible to invoke methods from your project. But I repeat, consider using JSR223 and Groovy, see [How to Reuse Your JMeter Code with JAR Files and Save Time](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-reuse-your-jmeter-code-with-jar-files-and-save-time) for detailed instructions